# UIPageViewController programmatically allow datasource to be called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` that displays images with `Transition style scroll`. I want to handle `tap` and `pan` gestures so in order to do that, I did a little hack of putting another `view` on top of the `uipageviewcontroller` and assign `tap` and `pan` gesture recognizers. In this case, i use `-setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` to perform swipes when i detect pan gestures to the left or right.

My problem is that when using  `-setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` the datasource methods `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` doesn't get called. Also the Delegate method `-pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:` doesnt get callled.

what do i have to do for these methods to be called using `setViewControllers`?

Answer (score 2):

<del>I think you can get UIPageController's [gesture recognisers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPageViewController/gestureRecognizers), and use them for disable or enable  UIPageController interaction by using method of [UIGestureRecogniser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/requireGestureRecognizerToFail:):</del>

```
- (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

If you use **setViewControllers...** methods of dataSource will not called, because you've provided viewControllers. Also you can handle completion of appearing animation in the completion block of this method. (you can call methods of the dataSource and delegate by self)

**UPD**

When I had same task, I implemented custom page view (based on UIScrollView in pages state), and used gesture recognisers of the scrollView to avoid scrolling, while pan gesture is recognised inside some page. I can't remember why I've implemented custom control, maybe because I can't find solution for same problem. I remember that my page view used dataSource to get views for the pages. I think you can implement custom control with your special logic.

Comment: UIPageViewController with Transition Style Scroll doesn't return any Gesture recognizers. it's only of the Transition style page curl :(

Comment: Thank you! when you mentioned i can handle the completion block my self, it gave me an idea to solve my problem. Shall I mark this as an answer or should I post my solution as another answer?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know here :).